# concatenating .txt files into a csv file with a tab delimiter

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

I am trying to concatenate a set of .txt files using windows command line, into a csv file.

so i use

```
type *.txt > me_new_file.csv
```

but a the fields of a given row, which is tab delimited, ends up in one column. How do I take advantage of tab separation in the original text file to create a csv file such that fields are aligned in columns correctly, using one or more command lines? I am thinking there might be something like...

```
type *.txt > me_new_file.csv delim= '  '
```

but haven't been able to find anything yet.
Thank You for your help. Would also appreciate if someone could direct me to a related answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the command line you'd have a fairly complicated time of it.  The Windows cmd.exe command processor is much, much simpler than dash, ash, or bash, et.al.

Best thing would be to concatenate all of your files into the .csv file, open it in a text editor, and do a global find and replace replacing  with ,

Be careful that your other data doesn't have any commas in it.

Answer (score 0):

If the source files are tab delimited, then the output file is also tab delimited. Depending on the software you are using, you should be able load the tab delimited data properly.

Suppose you are using Excel. If the output file has a .csv extension, then Excel will default to comma delimited columns when it opens the file. Of course that does not work for you. But if you rename the file to have some other extension like .txt, then when you open it with Excel, it will open a series of dialog boxes where you can specify the format, including tab delimited.

If you want to keep the .csv extension and have Excel automatically open it properly, then you need to transform the data. This can be done very easily with [JREPL.BAT - a hybrid JScript/batch utility that performs a regular expression search and replace on text data](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044). JREPL.BAT is pure script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

The following encloses each value in quotes, just in case a value contains a comma literal.

```
type *.txt 2>nul | jrepl "\t" "\q,\q" /x /jendln "$txt='\x22'+$txt+'\x22'" /o output.csv
```

***Beware:*** Your use of `type *.txt` will fail if the last line in any of your source .txt files does not end with a newline. In such a case, the first line of the next file will be appended to the last line of the previous file. Not good.

You can solve that problem by processing each file individually in a FOR loop.

```
(for %F in (*.txt) do jrepl "\t" "\q,\q" /x /jendln "$txt='\x22'+$txt+'\x22'" /f "%F") >output.csv
```

The above is designed to run on the command line. If used in a batch script, then a few changes are needed:

```
(for %%F in (*.txt) do call jrepl "\t" "\q,\q" /x /jendln "$txt='\x22'+$txt+'\x22'" /f "%%F") >output.csv
```

**Note:** My answer assumes none of the source files contain quotes. If they do contain quotes, then a more complicated search and replace is required. But it still can be done efficiently with JREPL.

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed reply. I ended up solving this problem yesterday, with a collegues help. what we did was a two stepper. first concatenate the files, the way I wrote in my question. then replace the tabs with a comma, which seemed to do the trick. I will write our solution some where up there later.

Comment: @SasonTorosean - If any of your tab delimited source files contain commas, then you will get the wrong result if you simply replace tabs with commas. You should enclose your values in quotes, as my answer does.